# Wordpress 3.8: jQuery not working - no errors

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

OK,

so I've got this weird situation. I'm trying to include Paul Underwood's simple smooth scroll script (http://www.paulund.co.uk/smooth-scroll-to-internal-links-with-jquery) in a Wordpress one-pager running on Wordpress 3.8.1.
However, the smooth scroll ain't working.

The script works perfectly on JFiddle, I've checked it for errors, but it's a simple copy-paste from the source, so that shouldn't be the problem. I'm pretty sure I've enqueued it properly in functions.php (yes, I also registerd jQuery). And it should work in noConflict.

So what am I missing here? It won't surprise me if it's a stupid little mistake...

Anyway, thanks in advance everyone :)

The HTML:

```
<a href="#main"><img class="arrow" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/arrow-down.png" alt="scroll down"></a>
```

The script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

$('html, body').stop().animate({
  'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
  window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});

});
```

the functions.php

```
function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured it out, guys.

As I predicted, it was some stupid little thing.

There was a relic

```
body{overflow-x: hidden}
```

in my stylesheet.

This is what's been trolling me - removed the line, and now everything works fine.

Thanks for the help, though :-)

Answer (score 0):

As your code says that you have two `doc ready` handlers and you can remove the inner `doc ready` first line is better:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // keep it, its better.

   $(document).ready(function() { //<---remove this line and its closing
```

so final code should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
              'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
              window.location.hash = target;
        });  // end of animate
    });  // end of click
}); // end of doc ready
```

Comment: Hey Jai, thanks for the tip. I've tried removing the extra handler, but unfortunately, the script still isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses `jQuery` instead of `$` by default. Try to replace all your `$`'s to `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = jQuery(target);

        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });  // end of animate
    });  // end of click
}); // end of doc ready
```

Try this one.

**EDIT:** Oh, I've just seen that you are giving the `$` as a parameter of the function. My fault.

But have you checked if you probably include jQuery twice?

Comment: Hey appnic, I checked the console and jQuery is only included once in the header. Wordpress did automatically include jquery-migrate, could that have any effect?

Comment: I don't think so, because jQuery-migrate just adds some functions which are deprecated but implemented in some older plugins (to ensure compatibility).